# Only use Ajax on links with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've gotten my wordpress theme to load page content using ajax. The only issue I'm running into is if I want to control what links to load content with. The simplest way I can think of doing this is by using classes on my  tags.

I can limit what links activate ajax by using a :not

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*='/wp-admin/']):not([href*='/wp-login.php']):not([href$='/feed/']):not('nonajaxlink')", function() {
    location.hash = this.pathname;
    return false;
});
```

But if I went with this method I would have to give ALL links not being used with ajax a special class.

I've also tried this:

```
$('.ajaxlink').click(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*='/wp-admin/']):not([href*='/wp-login.php']):not([href$='/feed/'])", function() {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
        return false;
    });
});
```

But the ajax seems to ignore the click function and just does it anyway.

Is there a way where I can only select certain links to use my ajax? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your second example, you have bound a click handler which simply binds another click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*='/wp-admin/']):not([href*='/wp-login.php']):not([href$='/feed/']).ajaxlink", function() {
    location.hash = this.pathname;
    return false;
});
```

With this, you set the selector to only those that have the class ajaxLink.

Comment: What's `jaxa`?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Bam this worked. Thank you! I didn't know you could add a class selector like that. So learned something new. Rock on :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, copy paste typo,  its corrected now, thanks @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to be generic, look for `.ajaxLink` south of the `document`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.hash = e.target.pathname;
});
```

Comment: I tried this prior to the above, which solved my issue, and but this didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but if you want to select only the links with your custom class, this is how you do it.